# Is it ok to use exit(1) to abort the program or should you attempt to return 1 from the main()?

Tags: c

I have used exit(1) extensively in my code because it does (I hope) exactly what I want - abort the program. I nicely print an error message (or put it into stderr), and then I just leave.

But I heard some schools of thought that this is bad for some reason and I don't understand why. The amount of work one would need to return an error value from every function where it is possible, and then navigate through cascading returns back to main so the program exits "naturally"... Is there a difference?

Are there specific scenarios where it matters? Even when I use errno and perror(), it is still much easier to just exit(1) from the point where the error occurred and without making the code less readable.

Do I have your blessing to use exit(1) ?

Comment: Failing fast is good. Using `exit(1)` is fine.  I do it all the time.  Beware of forcing it on users of any library functions you write.  That may limit their usefulness.

Comment: @pmg — there's always `atexit()` for getting cleanup done with `exit()`.  Using `_exit()` instead prevents that cleanup.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Note that `_exit` is a Unix routine. `_Exit` is the C standard routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a choice to make for yourself.

If you're writing a library, you really ought to report failure to the caller, which may be able to recover in ways you can't internally, and which might need to perform other cleanup that's not done by registered `atexit()` handlers.

If your code might be called from C++ or other high-level languages, then again, don't unilaterally exit, as that prevents destructors running to perform similar cleanup.

When you check memory use using Valgrind, then `exit()` will leave lots of objects in the "still accessible" state, making it harder to find your real leaks.

So I generally recommend returning from `main()`, but would tolerate some use of `exit()` in program-specific code that's never going to end up in a library.

Comment: If a program has a “need to perform other cleanup that's not done by registered atexit() handlers”, it is flawed because that is what it is supposed to use `atexit` handlers for.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  But people write flawed programs all the time, unfortunately, and you might not have the capacity to fix them when introducing the library.  Also, we might not be able to, due to the implementation-defined limit on number of `atexit()` functions (especially problematic given there's no way to unregister a function that's no longer required)

Answer (score 1):

The C library function `void exit(int status);` terminates the calling process immediately. Any open file descriptors belonging to the process are closed and any children of the process are inherited by process 1, init, and the process parent is sent a SIGCHLD signal.

So, we are know that `exit()` function causes to kill the current program, but remember to `free()` any **heap** allocated resources (*if you can*) before calling the `exit()` function.
So, using the `exit()` is absolutely okay.

Comment: Any open output file streams are flushed before the underlying file descriptor is closed.

Comment: `exit` does not terminate immediately. It calls exit handlers. `_Exit` is the most direct standard exit routine. In between are `quick_exit` (calls quick_exit handlers but not exit handlers), `abort` (does not call exit handlers but will cause `SIGABRT` handler to be called if enabled, where `_Exit` will not).

Comment: In a general-purpose multi-user operating system, there is no benefit to calling `free` before `exit`. The operating system will free the memory, and calling `free` instead of letting the operating system handle it can actually slow things down as it may cause swapped-out memory to be swapped in as the memory management routines need to work with their data structures.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know it is not compulsory to `free` every heap allocation, but `freeing` heap allocation is a `good practice in C`.

Comment: I have said `(if you can)` in the answer which was directly pointing towards your point of `not freeing every heap allocation.`